# How to get MessageBuilder status in Protocol Buffers?

Tags: protocol-buffers

When using Message.Builder.build() an exception is thrown when a required field is not set. Is there way to find out if the exception will be thrown? i.e. something like an iSReadyToBuild? There is a buildPartial method but it does not say whether the build was complete or partial.

Comment: You could simply run the "build()" method and if you catch the exception then you know it's not ready =)

Comment: Yeah was just looking for some cleaner looking code. As I have to handle this case and I don't like mixing exception handling in with code logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking for is called "[isInitialized()](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLiteOrBuilder#isInitialized%28%29)".